# Ruby Hash Fetch Issue with Sass

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I'm at a loss. Hoping somebody with more Ruby experience will tell me what is going on.

I'm calling a custom Sass function from my stylesheet like so:

```
$color: user_var('color')
```

The custom function looks like this:

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def user_var(param_name)
    puts options[:custom]
    puts options[:custom].fetch('color')
    puts options[:custom].fetch(param_name)
  end
end
```

The result of `puts options[:custom]` (as expected) is this:

```
{"color"=>#eeeeee, "header"=>20px}
```

The result of `puts options[:custom].fetch('color')` is #eeeeee

BUT... the result of `puts options[:custom].fetch(param_name)` results in a "key not found: 'color' (KeyError)".

Completely baffled here.

Comment: What you have here looks ok. You might need to go into this with a debugger to find out what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that param_name is a symbol and the color key in the options hash is defined as a string.

this should work.

```
options[:custom].fetch("#{param_name}")
```